# Send string with Eventaggregator

Tags: c#

How i can send string between two modules (between two textbox) using event aggregator?
How to call my inputed text binded to the first module textbox to the second module textbox,do i need one class with string properties which implemets my getevent?
I'm using WPF Prism.

Comment: You are going to need to expand the question to include such details as what tech stack you're using... Is your project WPF, Windows Forms, Nancy, ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm using Wpf Prism.

Comment: Presumably your textboxes are bound to view models? Have the view model send an event via the event aggregator to the other view model updating the property the text box is bound to.

Comment: Yes.My textboxes are bound to view models.I dont know how to send the string between view models between modules.Text="{Binding InputText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" . _EventAggregator.GetEvent<SendString>().Publish(InputText); .How to catch inputed text into the second textbox

Comment: In the view model you wish to update, you need to subscribe to the event. When subscribing you provide a lambda. In here you need to update the property that the text box you wish to update is bound to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view model you wish to update, you need to subscribe to the event. When subscribing you provide a lambda. In here you need to update the property that the text box you wish to update is bound to.

```
public class SourceViewModel
{
    public string SourceText { ... }
    // Publish SendString event on SourceText changes...
}

public class DestinationViewModel
{
    private IEventAggregator _aggregator;
    // Bind DestinationText to your destination text box...
    public string DestinationText { .. }

    public DestinationViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        ...
      _aggregator.GetEvent<SendStringEvent>().Subscribe(StringAction2,
        ThreadOption.UIThread, false, i => DestinationText = i.Text);
    }    
}
```

There is a good Prism EventAggregator sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample).